# Why does my non-static GameObject lose its reference in a script after scene reloaded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, scene, gameobject

I have an empty GameObject on my Canvas used to display an ad menu, which I have attached to a separate script (not on the menu itself) in a public variable through the inspector.

I am setting it inactive in a script using `adMenu.SetActive(false)`, which works on the first playthrough of my game. However, when I restart the scene through a button in my scene, the menu loses its reference to the same GameObject in the inspector, and I receive this error:

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
```

This has never happened to me with other GameObjects initialized in similar ways after a scene reload.

Additional details:

- `GameObject.Find()` can retrieve the GameObject using its name from within the same script
- `DontDestroyOnLoad()` is not used anywhere on the script or on the GameObject it's attached to

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using MEC;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{
    internal static AdManager instance;
    private static bool isInitialized = false;

    public GameObject adMenu;
    private string placement = "rewardedVideo";

    void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            isInitialized = true;
            Advertisement.AddListener(this);
            Advertisement.Initialize(Constants.appleGameId, true);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator<float> ShowAd()
    {
        if (!Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            yield return Timing.WaitForOneFrame;
        }
        Advertisement.Show(placement);
    }

    public void CloseAdMenu()
    {
        Debug.Log("Is adMenu null: " + (adMenu == null));  // Returns false on first playthrough only
        adMenu.SetActive(false);
    }


    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            CloseAdMenu();
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId)
    {
        // throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
    {
        // throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId)
    {
        // throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check the flow caused by the singleton pattern. The static instance may still be pointing to the AdManager instance from the previous scene. Even if static reference is updated, the event calling CloseAdMenu() (perhaps OnUnityAdsDidFinish) may be called before AdManager.Start(), causing the static reference to previous scene used before it is updated to the one in current scene. In general, connect all dependencies in Awake() to minimize this kind of risk, or, even try to avoid singleton pattern as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens has nothing to do with your menu object nor the `static` Instance.

The issue is the callback of

```
public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
```

since you registered the instance via

```
Advertisement.AddListener(this);
```

but `this` instance will be Destroyer after the scene was changed.

As shown in [the examples](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity) you should do

```
private void OnDestroy() 
{
    Advertisement.RemoveListener(this);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks, but why exactly does the error traceback point to my `adMenu.SetActive(false)` line instead of not even running `OnUnityAdsDidFinish()`?

Answer (score 0):

On your restart method, you should re-activate the button with `adMenu.SetActive(true)`, if not, when you call the scene again, `adMenu` `GameObject` is disabled, so you can't access the `GameObject`.

Maybe you can add a method in your AdManager like:

```
public void OpenAdMenu()
{
    adMenu.SetActive(true);
}
```

and call it on `AdManager.Start()`